# Unable to access another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, modular

I have uploaded a sample code where there are two objects defined using the modular pattern.

```
var obj1 = {
    cachdom: function() {
      // querying a dom element
      this.$interactiveReport = $('#BugPreventiveIR_data_panel');

      }
    };

    var obj2 = {
      $IR: obj1.$interactiveReport,
      logging: function() {
        // This returns undefined
        console.log(this.$IR);
      }
    };

    // Invoking the Objects only after document is ready.
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.clear();
      interactiveReportRegion.init();
      displayOfBugList.logging();
    });
```

However, when I check in console the obj2.logging returns undefined for this.$IR. However, if I were to access obj1.$interactiveReport through console I can view the object values. Similairly, if I were to define the second object in the console again, it obtains the correct value for obj2.$IR.

Any reason I am unable to access the first object's properties in the second object?

My entire code can be found here
https://gist.github.com/alaghu/6225e50b35ecfdaf2ee8f752f596f49b

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but you're missing a curly brace  in cachdom

Comment: The missing `}` is at the end of `obj1`.

Comment: Where do you set the variables `interactiveReportRegion` and `displayofBugList`?

Comment: Hi Barmar/user3685285, I am sorry about the missing }. I have included that in my edit. I do not thing that is the issue.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I am setting the variable "this.$interactiveReport" inside the cacheDom function.

Comment: The wierd part is that I can paste the exact code in the console for displayOfBugList and notice the variables and logging work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The logging function needs to know what "this" means since it's not a constructed object.. this should do it.

```
displayOfBugList.logging.apply(displayOfBugList);
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error if I add this to the logging function.

Comment: i don;t see anything in your given code that would do that. post the entire code.

Comment: Hi , it is available at https://gist.github.com/alaghu/6225e50b35ecfdaf2ee8f752f596f49b

Answer (score 0):

defining a function changes the scope for "this". Consider using lamda functions to fix this. There is also the ability to bind what "this" is but I shy away from that method

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thanks for your feedback. However, I do not understand why even this (line 40 )   // Similairly even this comes up as undedefined but is accessible through console
        console.log (interactiveReportRegion.$interactiveReport); does not work even though I am accessing it through obj.property.

Comment: If lamda function didn't change the output then my instinct is its something to do with jQuery. I would look there